# building a web application with SignalR

Tags: .net, signalr

I'm using signalR to build a .net web application and have dounts about the necessary technology, if I'm using signalR to all client-server and server-client interaction, why do I need to implement WebAPI or MVC? couldn't I just create a regular c# HUB class and use it for the interactions ? is using Web Forms, Web API or MVC really necessary ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is not necessary implemment WebAPI, MVC or any framework, in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) tutorial it explain

Only you need implement the 7 first steps

I hope I've helped! Regards

PD: Sorry about my english, is very basic.